# Databricks SQL Connector for Python - how to cancel inflght exeuct

Tags: databricks, databricks-sql

we are trying to run the cursor.execute(query) in a separate thread, and would like user to cancel this query while it is still running, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `cancel` method in the cursor class that could be used to stop already executing query. Check [connector documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/python-sql-connector.html#cancel-method) for more details, for example, you need to call `close` to clear used resources